# Highcharts animation not smooth on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts

I have issue with `highcharts` spline chart. The problem is that on **chrome** browser animation is not smooth, on other browsers animation works well.
So the question is, what can be problem that Chrome is not processing graph as it should.

```
$(function () {
  history_points_graph = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            animation: true,
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: function(){
                    //history_points_graph = this;
                    //applyFilterGraph_1(1,1);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2
        },
        legend: {
                enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 4,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            dataGrouping:false,
            enableMouseTracking:false,
            animation:{
                duration:1000
            },
            data: [[1096063200,524],[1285624800,429]]
        }]
    });  


});
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: check the console whether there are any errors..

Comment: there is no error... I would be glad if there is an error. Maybe there is something wrong with container css?

Comment: Could you post live example of your chart, so we can investigate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with transition on Chrome. Simply the page where I load graph I added css code.

```
  *{-webkit-transition: all 0ms ease !important; transition: all 0ms ease!important;}
```